# Assosiate mathematic equation in data base for runtime processing with JAVA

Tags: java, database, type-conversion

I am currently running a student project where I receive physical sensor values with java.

To convert the sensor values (from one physical dim. into an other physical dim), each sensor has a specific input data type (8bit, 16bit, double, etc.) and a mathematical equation for the data conversion. This configuration should be stored in a database (directly or a link to a script)

How would you recommend to implement such a feature?

Conversion example:
Sensor0 sends its value, the application should look in the database, how the sensor value of Sensor0 has to be converted. It fetches the conversion equation and converts the value.
(e.g. Output value is calculated with: `output_val = (input_val^2) * pi / (2*inputval))`

The previous mathematical equation should be stored somehow as a database entry or script definition for various sensors and should be processed at runtime.

My test system is a debian x86 computer with java runtime and a mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Calculation` abstract class with a `calculate` method, then create one inheriting class per sensor, e.g. `Input_1 extends Calculation`.  Then serialize `Input_1`, e.g. using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), and store the serialized instance in your database.  When you need to perform a calculation, read in the serialized instance, deserialize it, and run its `calculate` method.

As an alternative, create one class that performs all of the necessary input calculations, then serialize and deserialize it as necessary.  Whichever makes the most sense with your database.

The simplest way to serialize and deserialize a class is to use the default Java serializer, like so.

```
public abstract class Calculation {
    public double conversion(double d);
}

public class Sensor_34 extends Calculation implements Serializable {
    public double conversion(double d) {
        // conversion code
    }
}

ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
Sensor_34 sensor34 = new Sensor_34();
objectOut.writeObject(sensor34);
objectOut.close();
byte[] saveThisValue = byteOut.toByteArray(); // save the byte[] to the database

// ***

byte[] input = Database.read(); // read the byte[] back from the database
ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputSteam(byteIn);
Calculation calculation = (Calculation)objectIn.readObject();
// Now use the calculation object's "conversion" method to perform the conversion
```

So in summary, serialize a Sensor_34 object to a byte array and save it to your database, then read the byte array back in and convert it back into a Sensor_34 object.

Comment: Thanks for your help... But I don't want to create inheritances for each sensor.

Comment: In that case, either use one class that encompasses all of the sensor calculations, or else create one class per sensor without inheriting from an abstract class

Comment: Thanks for your help... But I don't want to create inheritances for every single sensor... All different sensors should be stored in the database and for every single sensor is a conversion function stored. For example: There are 100 different sensors (sensor_id from 0 to 99) in the database with 100 different conversion functions. Imagine sensor with ID 34 sends its sampled value to the application. At this point the application should look in the database which calculation method should be used for the specific sensor and perform the conversion...

Comment: The idea is that a sensor's conversion function is stored in a serialized class, e.g. public class Sensor_34 { public double conversion(double d) { return d * 4 + 3.4; }}; you read in the serialized class, deserialize it, and call its conversion method.  This way you don't need to parse any equations, they're already in an executable form.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not the best java developer :) As I understand your solution, I need to implement a class definition for every sensor id in the source code? ... 


My approach was that I store the whole knowledge of the valid sensor types and conversion information in the database tables. 

The end user should be able to declare all valid sensor types with the sensor IDs and the conversion functions just with the database.

Comment: The application itself should operate very modular. It does not know the conversion functions or anything about the sensors.

If a sensor sends its value with the sensor id to the application the following procedure should be executed:

Comment: The appl. queries the database if the sensor id is valid. If the sensor id is not stored in the db the value is dropped. If the sensor id is valid the application looks for the corresponding conversion equation in the database. If there is no equation stored for the actual sensor, the value should be directly taken over in the sensor logging table. Otherwise the application should fetch the conversion function, perform the conversion and store the value in the sensor logging table.

Would be nice if you could give me a short example of your concept. thx :)